# Тире или двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

Скажите, пожалуйста, в нижеприведённых двух предложениях должно стоять двоеточие или тире? Я знаю, что тире ставится перед одиночным приложением, а что делать, когда их два или более? Они тогда переходят в разряд перечислений или как?

**1. Проект был рождён благодаря взаимодействию двух компаний: “IJS & Zopie” и “Odenwald Organics”.

2. Они обладают двумя функциями: вибрацией и собственной методикой музыкального обучения.**

Answer (score 2):

В этих предложениях однородные члены предложения (названия компаний в 1 предложении и конкретные названия функций во 2) носят характер **приложения**. Можно поставить тире.

Розенталь. "Справочник по русскому языку. Пунктуация": "Если **однородные** члены предложения носят характер **приложения** или **уточнения**, то вместо двоеточия после обобщающего слова ***может ставиться тире***: Алый свет нежно заливал окрестности – ветряную мельницу, шиферные крыши машинно-тракторной станции, элеваторы (Кат.); Легенды и сказки любят все – дети и взрослые; Положительные черты характера проявляются всё равно в чём – в сдержанности, в терпеливости, в смелости; Друг мой был человек замечательный – умный, добрый, чуткий, готовый в любую минуту прийти на помощь".

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что двоеточие корректно. Простые предложения с обобщающими словами перед однородными членами.

"Однородные члены конкретизируют содержание понятия, выраженного обобщающим словом, поэтому между ним и однородными членами существует пояснительная свяаь, которая находит свое выражение в наличии или возможности вставки слов а именно, как-то, то есть и др." - Розенталь. Словарь лингвистических терминов.

Answer (score 1):

Да, здесь обобщающие слова перед однородными членами. В этом случае ставится двоеточие.

Answer (score 1):

Какой поставить знак - тире или двоеточие, - может подсказать интонация. Если она нисходящая, как в данных примерах:

*1. Проект был рождён благодаря взаимодействию двух компаний...* (интонацию можно обозначить стрелкой вниз) -

ставится двоеточие. При восходящей - тире (как в 1-м предложении моего комментария: уточнение *тире или двоеточие* обособлено двумя тире). Но это лишь вспомогательный критерий выбора знаков препинания. Конечно же, в первую очередь необходимо следовать правилам пунктуации, а именно - знаки препинания при однородных членах предложения.

Тем не менее, есть такая закономерность, независимо от того, сложное или простое предложение: восходящая интонация перед тире (часто после тире следует продолжение предложения) и нисходящая перед двоеточием.